# How do I combine two identical dataframes together with some replacement of values in one column?

Tags: r

I have a simple concept issue here and would need some help!

Here is my code:

```
Rank <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
ID <- c("Jack", "Tom", "Chloe", "Mary", "Max")

df <- data.frame(ID, Rank)

rankrange <- subset(df, Rank >2)

for (i in 1:nrow(rankrange)){ #revaluing numbers 3,4,5 with NA
  rankrange[i,2] <- "NA"
}

    ID   Rank
3 Chloe   NA
4  Mary   NA
5   Max   NA
```

> How do I combine df & rankrange such that the values for Chloe, Mary
>   and Max are replaced with NA in df?

I hope to get this result:

```
    ID   Rank
1 Jack    1
2 Tom     2
3 Chloe   NA
4  Mary   NA
5   Max   NA
```

I think this can be achieved with a function but I do not know which! Thanks!

**Edit**

I'm trying to understand what happens in the event I have two identical dataframes yet there's a variation in values for one column. What function can I use to combine these two dataframes together such that the values are replaced?

Comment: You  don't need a loop `df$Rank[df$Rank> 2] <- NA`

Comment: Hi akrun, I know that your method works. I'm just curious about the situation whereby I have two dataframes and would like to combine them together with value replacement! The above example I gave is a simplified version of what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: Hi snoram, rbind will only combine by rows, giving me duplicated entries of Chloe, Mary and Max.

Comment: If there are two data.frames, use `match` or `merge` when there is a common column

Comment: BTW, you are creating a stirng "NA" instead of just doing the assignment `rankrange$Rank <- NA`

Answer (score 0):

What exactly you are hoping for is still a bit unclear but here is an example that fits your data:

```
rbind(
  df[!df$ID %in% rankrange$ID, ], 
  rankrange
)

     ID Rank
1  Jack    1
2   Tom    2
3 Chloe   NA
4  Mary   NA
5   Max   NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
df$Rank <- ifelse(df$Rank > 2, NA, df$Rank)

     ID Rank
1  Jack    1
2   Tom    2
3 Chloe   NA
4  Mary   NA
5   Max   NA
```